# How to use ansible to run a shell file which needs an interrupt action

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible

I'm using ansible 1.9.4 to run a shell bash in server, and I have a trouble.
For example, I have a jdk file named *jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin* 
and I want to do something like the command below to install java:

```
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin
```

But when I run this command, the screen shown me the License Agreement and asked me "Press space or Enter" to scroll that, then press "yes" to confirm.

Or when I try to run a shell bash that includes something like:

```
echo "restart ntp ?[y/n]"
read check
```

I have tried it in ansible by *shell, script, command* modules but it didn't run for me, ansible was paused. Look like ansible was waiting for my interrupt action.
How can I do this? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `yes` like so: `yes | ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin`. Also there is the more powerful `expect` in case `yes` is too simple. (you can install expect with apt-get `apt-get install expect`)
So if your ansible action is `shell` it would be something like: `- shell: yes | ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin`

Comment: wow. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. But what should I do when I have to input more arguments ? For example, when I run the shell that includes some code like :       echo "input your name"  
    read name  
    echo "input your age?"  
    read age

Comment: In that case `expect` is the solution. Here are some examples http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/ so basically you do an install first to figure out what output (questions) you expect from your jdk install and then put these in the script so that expect can send the right answer at the given time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `yes` (see: `man yes`) or `expect`. Whereas `yes` continuously sends y answer to any process:

```
 yes | install.sh
```

`expect` will *listen* for an expect output and then send a reply accordingly.

(install `expect`, `apt-get install expect`, `yes` should be a part of you linux distro already)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10
spawn ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin

expect "Input your name:"
send "Quoc Lap\r"

interact
```

This little script will output your name if jdk install process ask for `"input your name:"`. Note that the name string ends with a return character `\r`

`interact` will make sure to close and send the proper exit code.

`man expect` will provide you with examples and info on how to deal with more complicated flows.

**Finally**

You ansible playbook will then need to call the script above

```
- name: Install Java JDK (automatic install)
  shell: ./jdk_install.sh
  args:
    chdir=/path/to/your/script
```

If you don't need to run from a specific location just prepend the path to the shell action and remove the args-part.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's all I need.
But I have something weird, and I can't explain.

This is my sources for testing:
_/var/tmp/run.sh:_

`#!/bin/bash
echo "add user"
passwd user`

_/var/tmp/run_script.sh:_

`#!/usr/bin/expect

cd /var/tmp
set timeout 10
spawn ./run.sh

expect "New password:"
send "123123\r"

expect "Retype new password:"
send "123123\r"
interact`

_main.yml:_

`- name: run test
  sudo: yes
  shell: /var/tmp/run_script.sh`

It was perfect when I  run shell `/var/tmp/run_script.sh` but when I run by ansible **user's password** wasn't changed.

Comment: Are you running as the same user from shell and from ansible? (remember that ansible can run as root or other user)

Comment: Yes, I'm running as the same user. And ansible doesn't get any error.

Comment: Could you try use a different action than `shell` e.g. `command`. `shell` AFAIK uses `/bin/sh` on the dest whereas `command` runs as the ansible user. That might make a difference.

Comment: Sorry but nothing was changed. Perhaps user is problem. I'm running shell `sudo /var/tmp/run_script.sh` as `vagrant user`, and in ansible's file I'm using `remote_user: vagrant` in `playbook` file. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Try to add to the task: `become: yes` to run as root (the default AFAIK). [See doc on become](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#new-directives)

Comment: what should I call this script then (what ending does this file need?)

Comment: Flotolk, the script can be named anything. The important part is the first line that tells the shell which program to use to execute the script. (In my example I named it `jdk_install.sh`. But `jdkInstall` would be just as valid. The Anible playbook should end in `.yml` or `.yaml`. Also make sure to make the script executable: `chmod +x jdkInstall`.